# Any easy way to bulk import 800 products into Shopify?

Tags: csv, shopify, bulk-import

So I have a bridal boutique client who I am setting up a Shopify store for and they are wanting to import around 800 prom dresses. The issue I am having is I have around 7 total designers and each has either given a PDF price sheet that consists of style, price, color and material or a excel spreadsheet that are all formatted differently.

I understand Shopify has the CSV import functionality, but having to copy and paste over 800 dresses each with specific colors, styles and different pricing seems like a very tedious and time consuming task. There HAS to be an easier way, it's as if it would almost be "easier" to just add these products one by one not using the CSV sheet.

Any ideas on what would be easiest? Really could use some help on this one instead of spending days importing each dress one by one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since your pricing and details are locked up in PDF format, your options are limited. You could outsource to Mechanical Turk to have the PDF documents turned into basic data for import.

Comment: Appreciate the response, that is what I am thinking as well. I had built a little JS CSV formatter, but the way Shopify formats their spreadsheet is tough with the different variants. Not too mention the descriptions I need are not included in the CSV, only on the designers website. Well, looks like I am in for a long couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an online converter to convert all 800 PDFs to CSV. Try searching for 'PDF to CSV' on Google and you'll see a range:

pdftables.com

zamzar.com

convertio.co